# Issue with using isNaN()

Tags: javascript

Actually this is a simple program to check weather the number is divisible by 2 or not divisible by 2 or input given is not a number. According to my information `isNaN('berry)` should give me true as'berry' is a string but in my code this goes quite wrong.

The code is :

```
var isNum = function(number) {
  // My code goes here!
  if (number%2===0){
      return true
  }
  else if (isNaN(number)){
      console.log("enter the number not the string");
      return number                
  }
  else{   
      return false
  }
};
isNum('berry');
```

The code above returns me false when I run it. Any help will be appreciated. 
This is the screenshot  [image: isNaN]

Comment: Why don't you use `return !isNaN(number)`?

Comment: You should check `isNaN(number)` *before* checking `number%2===0`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat but if its returning false its actually coming to second else if as well

Comment: I tried it @RocketHazmat it's giving me same output again.

Comment: I've copied pasted your code in my console window and it runs exactly like what you want @KedarKodgire

Comment: Wait.  What's the issue/question here?  Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/32e4s72x/1/

Comment: I added a screenshot above @RocketHazmat.

Comment: @KedarKodgire: What do you see if you do `console.log(number_parsed)`?  Also, where are you testing this code, and in which browser?  I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: `isNum=x=>!!+x||x===0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert variables to their integer or float equivalent before use elsewhere.

You can try using `typeof` to determine the variable type.

```
var isNum = function(number) {
    var number_parsed = parseFloat( number );
    if (isNaN(number) || typeof number == 'string' ){
          console.log("enter the number not the string");
          return number                
    } elseif(number_parsed % 2 ===0){
        return true
    } else{   
        return false
    }
};
isNum('berry');
```

Comment: Thanks @PatrikMoore your code above is working absolutely fine,but i want to do it using "if,else if,else".

Comment: Yes @PatrikMoore it is working correctly now.And just one more doubt what does "parseFloat" and " || " do in above code as i'm new to this I never used this before, can you explain me little bit about this.

Comment: `||` is `or` in JS. So that line says if isNaN() evaluates true, OR, typeof number = 'string', then log to console & return number. `parseFloat()` turns any input into float (decimal number). So the string `"1.3"` is converted to float data type `1.3`

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives the following output (run it here) and it's correctly working

```js
var isNum = function(number) {
  // My code goes here!
  if (number%2===0){
      return true
  }
  else if (isNaN(number)){
      console.log("enter the number not the string");
      return number                
  }
  else{   
      return false
  }
};
isNum('berry');
```

Answer (score -1):

[`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) returns true when the argument is actually [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).  You provided `'berry`', not `NaN` and so `isNan()` returns false.

Quoting the documentation:

> The isNaN() function determines whether a value is NaN or not.

.

> Return value
>
> true if the given value is NaN; otherwise, false.

Comment: isNaN() returns boolean (true/false) of non-number/number respectively.

Comment: @MehulMohan not according to the documentation

Comment: isNaN('a') // true. | isNaN(1); // false; | 'a' == NaN // false. Fun fact: NaN == NaN // false.